# Ocropus 4.4. crashes on Xubuntu 10.4

Tags: compilation, ocr, ubuntu-10.04

I have problems with Ocropus 4.4. (open source OCR). I installed Ocropus and neccessary libries following [this script](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/wiki/InstallTranscript). Compilation/Installation goes without any problem.

However after successful installation of ocropus, I am not able to run any of ocropus-* commands. Ocropus-page and ocropus-hocr crash without giving any error meaningful message. I just get a cryptic killed after 2 minutes of processing.

```
ocropus-pages page_001.jpeg
[note] line recognizer:  >
[note] *** 1 page_001.jpeg ***
Killed
```

I do not know where to start to fix it. Has anybody an idea where to start?

My machine is XUbuntu 10.4  64bits (run in VirtualBox) with 512MB of base memory.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to convert your images to uncrompressed tiff before processing. I know that ocropus is working closely with tesseract and that tesseract handles 1bpp uncompressed tiffs the best.

Answer (score 0):

Despite this being an old question I thought I'd post a solution / some debug tips as I experienced the same problem under the same scenario. The scenario being: Debian running under VirtualBox with 512MB RAM

In order to debug "Killed" messages you should look into `/var/log` for help. In my case kern.log contained:

> debian kernel: [89675.791910] Out of memory: Kill process 13004
> (ocropus-rtrain) score 806 or sacrifice child
>
> debian kernel: [89675.791951] Killed process 13004 (ocropus-rtrain)
> total-vm:800816kB, anon-rss:412424kB, file-rss:4kB

It's likely you need to increase the amount of resources assigned to the VM particularly if you're running some big fancy window manager in the background!